# How to chain together two Combine publishers in Swift and keep the cancellable object

Tags: swift, combine

Does anyone know how to chain together two publishers with Swift + Combine and keep the cancellable so that I can cancel the pipeline later?
I have a method that accepts input from a publisher and outputs to a publisher:

```
static func connect(inputPublisher: Published<String>.Publisher, outputPublisher: inout Published<String>.Publisher) -> AnyCancellable {
    inputPublisher.assign(to: &outputPublisher)

    // Unfortunately assign consumes cancellable
}
```

Note that this method cannot access the wrapped properties directly. The publishers must be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to link two publishers but with the option to break that link at some point in the future.

I would try using `sink` on the `inputPublisher`, since that function gives me a cancellable, and then a `PassthroughSubject`, since I wasn't able to figure out how to pass the value from `sink` directly to `outputPublisher`.

It would look something like this:

```
static func connect(inputPublisher: Published<String>.Publisher, outputPublisher: inout Published<String>.Publisher) -> AnyCancellable {
  let passthrough = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
  passthrough.assign(to: &outputPublisher)
  let cancellable = inputPublisher.sink { string in
    passthrough.send(string)
  }
  return cancellable
}
```

Disclaimer: I wrote this on a Playground and it compiles, but I didn't actually run it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with `assign(to:)`, since it binds the lifetime of the subscription to the lifetime of the `Published` upstream (`inputPublisher` in your case) and hence you cannot manually cancel the subscription.

Instead, you can use `assign(to:on:)`, which takes an object and a key path and whenever the upstream emits, it assigns the value to the property represented by the key path on the object.

```
inputPublisher.assign(to:on:)

class PublishedModel {
    @Published var value: String

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let outputModel = PublishedModel(value: "")

// this returns an `AnyCancellable` that you can cancel
PublishedModel(value: "initial").$value.assign(to: \.value, on: outputModel)
```

You can also create a convenience method for this

```
func assign<Root, Value>(published: Published<Value>.Publisher, to keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Value>, on object: Root) -> AnyCancellable {
    published.assign(to: keyPath, on: object)
}

let outputModel = PublishedModel(value: "")
let inputModel = PublishedModel(value: "initial")
assign(published: inputModel.$value, to: \.value, on: outputModel)
```

Comment: I see this does work but having to create and then pass the PublishedModel around is pretty ugly. The method should be generic and not depend on a particular model. I would love to know how Apple implements their:
.assign(to: &outputPublisher)
so I can create a similar method that also returns the cancellable.

Comment: @Sam you don't need to use the `PublishedModel` in your actual code, you already have the `@Published` properties stored on a model that you can pass around. I just added that for better illustration.

Comment: I know, I want my API to be independent of the underlying model.

Comment: Unfortunately Combine closed source, so you cannot look at its implementation. Your best bet is checking [OpenCombine](https://github.com/OpenCombine/OpenCombine), which is a backwards compatible (pre-iOS 13) open source reimplementation of Combine, but bear in mind that its implementation might differ from that of Apple's and it is also lacking some features of Combine.

Comment: @Sam the API is independent of the model, you can modify your `connect` method to be generic over the model type

Comment: I'll check out the OpenCombine project thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Sam also check my updated answer, I've added a generic method similar to your `connect` using `assign(to:on:)`

Comment: thanks for the update! Solution looks good!